# Spring boot polymorphic request body using Jackson annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, swagger

I have an OpenAPI v3 spec and defined an 'anyof' body for one of my endpoints.

I am using the model classes generated from swagger-codegen v3 and they use Jackson annotation to define JsonSubTypes of these possible request bodies.

In my controller class, I use instanceof to check which body I am working with, but I cannot typecast the Parent class body as the child class pre-compile time, but I want to define the request body as the child class pre-compile time to pass it along to my service as an argument.

In this situation, is it better to create converter classes to convert Parent -> Child?

Example:

Policy Parent class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = 
JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(value = AutoInsurance.class, name = "AUTO_INSURANCE"),
    @Type(value = LifeInsurance.class) })
public class Policy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String policyNumber;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PolicyType policyType;
    private String name;

}
```

AutoInsurance class:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonTypeName(value = "AUTO_INSURANCE")
public class AutoInsurance extends Policy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String vehicleNumber;
    private String model;
    private String vehicleType;
    private String vehicleName;

}
```

LifeInsurance class:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonTypeName(value = "LIFE_INSURANCE")
public class LifeInsurance extends Policy {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "policy")
    private List<Dependents> dependents;
    private String medicalIssues;
    private String medication;
    private String treatments;

}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/policy")
public class PolicyController {

    @PostMapping
    public void savePolicy(@RequestBody Policy policy) {
        if (policy instanceof AutoInsurance) {
             AutoInsurance autoInsurance = (AutoInsurance) policy;
             service.processAutoInsurance(autoInsurance)
             ...
        } else if (policy instanceof LifeInsurance) {
             LifeInsurance lifeInsurance = (LifeInsurance) policy;
             service.processlifeInsurance(lifeInsurance)
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem.

We can use Jackson's ObjectMapper convert method to convert parent classes to child classes.

Documentation for ObjectMapper: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

Example of controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/policy")
public class PolicyController {
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper; // Define a ObjectMapper bean in your configuration class

    @PostMapping
    public void savePolicy(@RequestBody Policy policy) {
        if (policy instanceof AutoInsurance) {
             AutoInsurance autoInsurance = objectMapper.convertValue(policy, AutoInsurance.class);
             service.processAutoInsurance(autoInsurance);
             ...
        } else if (policy instanceof LifeInsurance) {
             LifeInsurance lifeInsurance = objectMapper.convertValue(policy, LifeInsurance.class);
             service.processlifeInsurance(lifeInsurance);
             ...
        }
    }
}
```